# Python error: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, nameerror

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt
import time

def grad_d():
    weight = [0, 0]
    learnrate = 0.01
    tol = 1.e-5
    itmax = 1000

    for i in range(itmax):
        deltaweight = - learnrate * opt.rosen_der(weight)
        weight = weight + deltaweight
        if abs(deltaweight) < learnrate:
            break
    
    return weight, i
    
print('Weight: ', weight)
print('Iterations: ', i)
```

After running the code, I receive error message:

"File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/gradientdescent.py", line 19, in 
print('Weight: ', weight)
NameError: name 'weight' is not defined

I am new to Python and I do not understand why it is saying that the variable "weight" is undefined when it clearly appears to be defined under grad_d().

Comment: You call `print(weight)` before you define `weight`

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to call your function
Try:

```
weight, i = grad_d()
print('Weight: ', weight)
print('Iterations: ', i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because for 'weight' variable in not in global scope and will work only inside the function.

you can define it on global level to resolve.

move `weight = [0, 0]` outside the `def grad_d()` should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

`weight` is defined inside the scope of the function `grad_d()`. Any code outside it can't see it. Please do study how scopes work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not calling the method. Do it like this:

```
weight, i = grad_d()
print('Weight: ', weight)
print('Iterations: ', i)
```

Secondly, `deltaweight` is a numpy array of shape `(2,)`. So, you need to make sure which element out of two elements you want to compare. If you want to compare both the elements you can use `deltaweight.any()` or `deltaweight.all()`.
Your entire code will be something like this (assuming you are comparing the first element of `deltaweight` array)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt
import time

def grad_d():
    weight = [0, 0]
    learnrate = 0.01
    tol = 1.e-5
    itmax = 1000

    for i in range(itmax):
        deltaweight = - learnrate * opt.rosen_der(weight)        
        weight = weight + deltaweight
        if abs(deltaweight[0]) < learnrate:
            break
    
    return weight, i

weight, i = grad_d()
print('Weight: ', weight)
print('Iterations: ', i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I seem to getting this error now:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/gradientdescent.py", line 21, in <module>
    weight, i = grad_d()
  File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/gradientdescent.py", line 14, in grad_d
    deltaweight = - learnrate * opt.rosen_der(weight)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'weight' referenced before assignment

Comment: Nevermind. That was my own fault. I had tried defining weight above the def grad_d() when trying your suggesting. After moving it back down under it, your suggestion worked fine. Thank you!